# Как сделать GET запрос ?to

Tags: php, html5, get

Я новичок в php и хочу сделать чтобы когда неавторизованный пользователь переходил на страницу для авторизованных, его перенаправляло на страницу авторизации с GET запросом ?to и в этом запросе была страница с которой его перенаправило. Потом при входе пользователя отправило на страницу, которая указана в get запросе ?to=....
Как мне это реализовать?

Comment: Может его не кидать туда-обратно. Каждая страница под авторизацией всё равно будет ее проверять.
Так пусть рисует логин диалог вместо содержимого.

Comment: Мне надо как в вк. Допустим я не авторизован и хочу перейти в сообщения. Страница сообщений проверяет мою авторизацию и видит, что я не авторизован и перекидывает на страницу с авторизацией и GET запросом на страницу сообщений(vk.com/login?to=зашифрованная страница сообщений). Потом когда я введу логин и пароль, меня перенаправит на сообщения

Comment: а до того, как попасть на страницу сообщений, для системы я просто гость, или я уже зашел собой, и у меня нет конкретно прав на страницу сообщений?

Comment: vk, скорее всего, редиректы не от хорошей жизни делала. Там система очень большая распределенная.

Comment: К странице сообщений вообще нет доступа. Нужна авторизация. И вот после авторизации чтобы меня перекинуло на страницу, которая меня кинула на авторизацию(сообщения к примеру)

Comment: Эти две страницы на разных серверах что-ли?
Вот, в документации, примеры: с `Location`
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php ,
 `urlencode`
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php

Comment: Ниже понасоветовали все, что можно, но ничего, что нужно..делайте проверку, авторизован ли пользователь (на конкретной странице). Если он не авторизован - редиректите его куда хотите. Например, так `header('Location: /auth.php?to=ССЫЛКА');`. Либо любым другим удобным способом

Comment: Вот и я про это. Только как сделать ссылку зашифрованной как в вк? К примеру ?to=hw5kw92h

Comment: про `urlencode` читали? или в другом смысле зашифрованной?  и зачем?

Comment: Меня кидает на страницу авторизации с get запросом ?to в котором коротко зашифрована ссылка страницы(к примеру hel7jw9lw), которая меня отправила на авторизацию. После входа нужно расшифровать обратно в ссылку и перенаправить на эту ссылку.

Comment: Скорее всего, она не зашифрована. Это можно сделать, например, таблицей с двумя колонками: короткая_ссылка, длинная_ссылка. Только я до сих пор не понял, зачем вы хотите кидать пользователя туда-сюда, вместо того, чтобы просто нарисовать ему логин-диалог на месте.

Comment: Так сейчас на многих сайтах. К примеру пользователь не авторизован и хочет зайти на страницу для авторизованных, то его просто отправит на страницу авторизации с get запросом. Ну а после авторизации, его не на главную отправит, а на ту страницу, на которую он хотел

Comment: Вот, например, туториал (там не про отправку, а про авторизацию вообще): https://htmlacademy.ru/tutorial/php/sessions-cookies

Comment: Я залогинился в gmail; У них 2 сайта: mail.google.com и accounts.google.com, на одном аутентификация, на другом письма. Между ними да -- переброс туда-сюда, всё разумно.

Comment: На ваших многих сайтах тоже по 2 сайта? а на том, который вы делаете? Где у вас форма аутентификации? Вы ее сами делаете?

Comment: А зачем Вам шифровать эту ссылку ? Вы там какие то секретные данные собираетесь хранить ? Как по мне - ерунда и просто трата "собственных сил". Да и зачем GET запрос для такой цели ? Возьмите и сохраните юзеру в куки адрес страницы на 100 сек, например, и, после авторизации, прочитайте куки и редиректните куда нужно. Это к слову об еще одном способе из многих

Answer (score -1):

Лучше реализовать что-то типо ACL(Access Control List) и прописать разные доступы пользователей.

Шаг 1 - Индентификация того кто перешёл на страницу
Шаг 2 - Смотришь его доступ в созданном ACL
Шаг 3 - Редиректишь в зависимости от доступа.

Пример ACL

```
return [
    'all' => [
        'index',
        'about',
        'contact',
    ],
    'authorize' => [
        'index',
        'about',
        'contact',
        'post',
    
    ],
    'guest' => [
        //
    ],
    'admin' => [
        //
    ],
];
```

У всех есть доступ к 3 страницам, у авторизованных к 4.

Answer (score -2):

После авторизации делайте редирект на $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] это предыдущий адрес
или подставляйте в значение ?to значения $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] перед редиректом на страницу авторизации